# Windows service is not getting uninstalled from Control Panel

Tags: windows-services

I have created a Windows service to do some batch processing. The service has been running well till last week. Last week i have re installed my OS. and installed the windows service again using the MSI package. But after installation the Service is not getting Displayed in the Service.msc however the Control panel shows the entry for the service. Now the problem is im not able to uninstall the service from control panel. When i tried to uninstall it is throwing Error1: The specified service does not exists as an installed service. Sc delete option also not able to delete the service from control panel.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To paraphrase:
As I understand it you're wanting to delete a service which hasn't installed cleanly?

You can either:

1. Use `sc delete <myservice>` (which I'm presuming from your question is unavailable?)
2. Delete the associated windows registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services` (search for your subkey)

Hope that helps!